# VBA from Excel failing to print via PDFCreator after loop

Tags: pdf, excel, vba

I've written some code to take info from 3 columns on tab one (1000 rows of data) to populate data on the second tab ( to make a form letter based on account information address etc). The code enters a Do While and the problem occures after the PDF is sent to the queue when the code continues the loop. The error only occurs when there running the code, when stepping through the code there are no issues.

I've tried this in both 2003 and 2007 with similar results (2003 will print 3 files and I've got 2007 to print up to 6 files)

I've also tried to add a manual delay with

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

and after the job enters the print queue

```
 Sleep 3000
```

I've also added a Do Until loop to wait for the print jobs to go down to zero with no success.

The complete code is:

```
Sub PlaceData()

Dim accountNumber As String
Dim partyID As String
Dim ClientAddress As String
Dim bRestart As Boolean
Dim totalAccounts As Long
Dim pdfjob As PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
Dim dataPage As Worksheet
Dim letterPage As Worksheet
Dim CB As Workbook 'CB = ClientBook

Set CB = ThisWorkbook
Set dataPage = CB.Sheets("Data")
Set letterPage = CB.Sheets("Letter")


'will iterate through the account numbers down

therow = 1
'where the loop starts
totalAccounts = dataPage.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do While therow < totalAccounts
therow = therow + 1

'for the form letter

letterPage.Range("F4").FormulaR1C1 = dataPage.Range("A" & therow)
letterPage.Range("F5").FormulaR1C1 = dataPage.Range("C" & therow)
letterPage.Range("B10").FormulaR1C1 = dataPage.Range("B" & therow)


'accountnumber minus one digit for the file name
accountNumber = letterPage.Range("F4").Text
accountNumberShort = Mid(accountNumber, 1, 8)

On Error GoTo EarlyExit
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set pdfjob = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
sPDFPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

'Check if PDFCreator is already running and attempt to kill the process if so

Do
    bRestart = False
    Set pdfjob = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
    If pdfjob.cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup") = False Then
        'PDF Creator is already running.  Kill the existing process
        Shell "taskkill /f /im PDFCreator.exe", vbHide
        DoEvents
        Set pdfjob = Nothing
        bRestart = True
    End If
Loop Until bRestart = False

With pdfjob
    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = sPDFPath
    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = accountNumberShort
    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0    ' 0 = PDF
    .cClearCache
End With

        'Delete the PDF if it already exists
        If Dir(sPDFPath & accountNumberShort) = accountNumberShort Then Kill (sPDFPath & accountNumberShort)

'Print the document to PDF

        letterPage.PrintOut copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="PDFCreator"

        'Wait until the print job has entered the print queue
        Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 1
            DoEvents
        Loop
        pdfjob.cPrinterStop = False

 'Wait until PDF creator is finished then release the objects

        Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 0
            DoEvents
        Loop

Loop

'where the loop will end and where the issue is (I think)

'cleanups

Cleanup:
'Release objects and terminate PDFCreator
Set pdfjob = Nothing
Shell "taskkill /f /im PDFCreator.exe", vbHide
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

EarlyExit:
'Inform user of error, and go to cleanup section
MsgBox "There was an error encountered.  PDFCreator has" & vbCrLf & _
       "has been terminated.  Please try again.", _
       vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
Resume Cleanup

Set CB = Nothing
Set dataPage = Nothing
Set letterPage = Nothing
Set pdfjob = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for any input or suggestions,

Comment: by no means is this a solution, but does killing spoolsv.exe at the same time as killing PDFCreator help?

Comment: @jonlester  no that doesn't see to help my issue. spoolsv.exe looks to not be going wonky as i've seen happen for some. I think I'll experiment more with the delay as I think the code is just not allowing the process to really get started

Comment: after some very experimental debugging (there's a beetle in there). I think I've found the main culprit these lines are the ones where it keeps hanging : Set pdfjob = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator If pdfjob.cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup") = False Then

Answer (score 0):

I would add correct disposal of **PDFCreator** (PDFC) after has done its job, because incorrect disposal can cause problems in repeated runs of PDFC (leftover process, resources etc.). All code samples shipped with PDFC implement disposal at least at its minimum, i.e. they call at least `clsPDFCreator.cClose()` method.

For instance, check sample file `C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator\COM\VB6\Sample1\Form1.frm` (adjust the path if you installed PDFC into different directory). Code found in the sample:

```
 If noStart = False Then
   PDFCreator1.cClose   ' sending cleanup&exit request to PDFCreator
   While PDFCreator1.cProgramIsRunning ' loop while PDFCreator is not found finished
     DoEvents
     Sleep 100 ' polling interval 100 ms
   Wend
 End If

 Set PDFCreator1 = Nothing
 Set pErr = Nothing
 Set opt = Nothing
```

Other shipped samples sometimes show some additional tricks but none miss the disposal part.